# Assign database value to hyperlink but not a runat=server

Tags: asp.net, jquery, html

Its simple if I have an ASP.net page with an ASP.net linkbutton / hyperlink
and I obtain a value from say a SQL Database and I store it in the label...

For example:

`this.myLabel.Text = someValueReturnedFromADatabase`

This is simple because it goes right to the code behind page and set the text value
to the value returned from my database (aside from going into more details with data access layer, etc).

What I was wondering is what if I dont want to use an ASP.net linkbutton and I simply want to use an HTML link button (as I need to call the jquery fade function).  How would I set the value someValueReturnedFromADatabase to a control that is not runat=server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a variable in your codebehind:

```
protected string TextForLabel
```

Set it in `Page_Load`, or wherever:

```
TextForLabel = someValueReturnedFromADatabase;
```

Reference it with pointy-bracket percent notation:

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/"><% =TextForLabel %></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set runat="server" on standard html controls. I do it all the time. Then you will be able to access their properties in your code behind just like you do for asp controls.

If I am not mistaken, for labels you can use .InnerText or .InnerHTML to change the text.

Comment: Why not? How is it different from using an asp control?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know of, you need to make some sort of relation between your HTML document and the code behind to interact with data from a SQL database. Either that or you'll have to make the entire database connection etc. in the HTML header using script type="text/javascript" and script type="text/C#" or whatever language you use to develop.